# What is a more compact way to write multiple if/else statements

Tags: algorithms, algpseudocode

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\usepackage[1,2,3,4]{pagesel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\algnewcommand\algorithmicforeach{\textbf{for each}}
\algdef{S}[FOR]{ForEach}[1]{\algorithmicforeach\ #1\ \algorithmicdo}



\begin{document}

\algdef{SE}[SUBALG]{Indent}{EndIndent}{}{\algorithmicend\ }%
\algtext*{Indent}
\algtext*{EndIndent}

\noindent
\newpage

\begin{algorithm}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{iterate}{$CART$}
  
  \ForEach{$t \in T$}
   
  \If{$ something2 $}
  \Indent
  \If{$something3$}
  \State $b_{d} = "L"$
  \ElsIf{$something4$}
  \State $b_{d} = "R"$
  \ElsIf{$something4$}
  \State $b_{d} = "-"$
   \EndIf
  \EndIndent
 \EndIf
 
\EndProcedure
```

What is a more compact way to write the if/ifelse statements since this notation makes the pseudocode very long.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @Mensch Thank you, nice to be a part of the community! Hopefully my first question is well posed :)

Comment: `T = [f(t1),f(t2),f(t3) ... f(tn)]`
` g(T)-> return f(t)`

Comment: @YiannisLazarides what about if statements?

Comment: You don't need the T[3] will return a function with a correct answer! I will write a longer answer in the morning (time zone issues). You can also use a case statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First to answer your question, I would have indicated it as per the image below,
which uses an array of functions.

[image]

Pseudocode represents an informal high level description of what one would program with a computer language.
Pseudocodes omit details like variable declarations, memory allocations, and computer language specific syntax. Too high a level, however, and we risk missing important details. The goal of pseudocode is to give enough cues to allow the reader to
write a working computer program, no matter what programming language will be
ultimately used to implement it.

The style of pseudocode in the image follows a particular style, I first saw in *Prime Numbers a Computational Perspective* by Crandall. This can be described a fusion of English and C-type languages (or Algol68 if you need to give credit to where credit belongs). This mix hopefully makes the algorithms more readable and the programmer can easily change these to her language of preference. Knuth used a similar style as well. If you interested in such a style, please post another question and I will post some code.

**Acid Test**

To implement your algorithm, say in LaTeX I would do

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
\newcounter{counter} 
\def\States{\elt A\elt B\elt C \elt D\elt E}%<-array
\def\GetState#1{
  \gdef\elt##1{
    \stepcounter{counter}
    \ifnum#1=\thecounter State: ->##1$_{\thecounter}$ \fi
   }
  \States  %<return
}
\GetState{2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The answer looks very detailed but I do not understand how this code will correspond to my situation. Is it like  [f(t1),f(t2),f(t3) ... f(tn)] = ("L","R","-")?

Comment: Yes it is like you wrote it.